Interpolation-extrapolation scales of H. Amann
I am currently reading H. Amann's notes titled "Nonhomogeneous linear and quasilinear elliptic and parabolic boundary value problems", and I have a question regarding the abstract interpolation-extrapolation method that is presented in these notes, specifically in section 6, "Abstract interpolation-extrapolation scales".
In that section, starting from $(E_0,E_1)$ (a densely injected Banach couple) and an operator $A_0$ that generates an analytic semigroup from $E_1$ to $E_0$, a scale of spaces $\{E_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is constructed. It is then observed that $E_0$ and $A_0$ can be "recovered" from $E_1$ and $A_1$ (by completing the space and extending the operator by density), and the same idea is applied to $E_0$ and $A_0$ to construct the spaces $E_{-1}$ and $A_{-1}$.
My question is: why not continue with this idea to keep constructing $E_{-k}$ and $A_{-k}$? In the notes, $E_{-2}$ and $A_{-2}$ are constructed by repeating the entire interpolation-extrapolation process starting from the pair $(E_{-1},E_0)$ and $A_{-1}$, which allows the scale to be extended to $k=−2$, but it requires replacing the already constructed spaces with isomorphic copies, which, according to Remark 6.1(a), seems to cause issues.
I understand there must be a reason for doing it this way, of course, but I am unable to see why. I would be immensely grateful if you could clarify my doubt.
$\textbf{EDIT:}$ I think I misread the article and he does precisely what I say. However, I keep wondering why in the process of constructing the "negative" spaces of the scale, the already constructed "negative" spaces are replaced by isomorphic copies.

Maybe you want to check (if you have not done so already) the corresponding chapter in Amann's book Linear and Quasilinear Parabolic Problems Volume I: Abstract Linear Theory. It is Chapter V.1.3, p.262/263.
